# iOS Universal link support in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, ios-universal-links, salesforce-ios-sdk

We are looking to deep link our mobile application from Web page.

As per apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) it require to have apple-app-site-association json file at root of https://xxx-salesforce.com/

Can anybody tell me how to place **apple-app-site-association** json file at **root** of salesforce domain?

We are using a visual force page where we want to put our app links.

Regards,

Manish Kumar

Answer (score 1):

You write that you are interested in deep linking into *your* mobile application from a web page. As you mention the AASA file, you must be talking about an iOS app and not an Android app. Check this link for a good overview of what is required to set up deep linking to iOS apps: https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9/. Note that you would have to configure your own AASA file and host that on your own domain, not the Salesforce domain. You would then be able to use the deep links you create on Salesforce pages - or any other web pages, for that matter.

If I have misunderstood and you are actually hoping to deep link into an app that has been written by Salesforce, well this is a situation where Salesforce themselves would need to host the AASA file and configure the iOS project to support the deep linking scheme. This is something that only Salesforce is in a position to do.

Comment: Hi @dwestgate, 

Thanks for your comment, As per my question we are using a VF page which is part salesforce. I am not sure that salesforce does allow to place AASA file at root? does it.

Comment: I have asked a few people now, and everyone has the same answer: they don't believe you could serve the AASA via Visualforce, but nobody had tried it. Which leads me to observe that this seems like an odd use case. If you could provide an outline of the user experience you are hoping to create, it might allow me (or someone else) to suggest other possible solutions that might be more easily implemented.

Comment: Ok, We are having a Salesforce SDK based mobile application. We also have a customised web version of that application that runs on VF page. So now customer can use both mobile and web version. We usually install this vf page at client via manage package. So it's always have thier environment specific url, and mobile app also use specific url (custom host). 

So here we want to create a single link that could open mobile app if clicked via mobile otherwise redirect to visual force page (web page, which is resposive).

Comment: There are a lot of moving pieces with Universal Linking, and once it is working you will discover there are tons of edge cases. I would recommend not complicating things by using the same domain for your mobile app's links as you are using for the Visualforce app. Instead, use a different domain and serve the AASA using a regular web server. An even easier option would be to leverage one of the free mobile linking services (Branch.io or Firebase's Branch knock-off). These services allow you to define link behavior to redirect to your responsive app page or to the App or Play stores as desired.

Comment: Thanks @dwestgate. Let me try that.